# edges minus vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there a more interesting name for this graph invariant: edges minus vertices?  It seems to have been called 'complexity' in

- Remco van der Hofstad, Joel Spencer, *Counting Connected Graphs Asymptotically*, European Journal of Combinatorics **27** Issue 8 (2006) 1294–1320, doi:[10.1016/j.ejc.2006.05.006](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2006.05.006), arXiv:[math/0502579](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502579)

and in

- Joel Spencer, *Probabilistic Methods in Combinatorics* In: Chatterji S.D. (eds) Proceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians,   Birkhäuser, Basel (1995), doi:[10.1007/978-3-0348-9078-6_132](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-9078-6_132), [Wayback Machine pdf of article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170811094846/http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1994.2/Main/icm1994.2.1375.1383.ocr.pdf), [big IMU pdf of whole volume](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1994.2/ICM1994.2.ocr.pdf)

The motivation is that we want to talk about a quantity that is preserved under the graph transformation of collapsing two distinct vertices connected by an edge to a single vertex (thereby removing one edge and one vertex, preserving 'edges minus vertices').  So for example if the quantity 'edges minus vertices plus one' is more natural for some reason and has a name, then this would also be helpful.  The concept should not be restricted to e.g. planar graphs.

Comment: You may have had this in mind already, but you need to be careful. If you collapse u~v into a single vertex, you only preserve |E|-|V| if u and v had no common neighbors.

Comment: Euler characteristic: it is the Euler characteristic of the one dimensional simplicial complex associated to the graph.

Comment: I guess I meant a multigraph or something instead of a graph.  For example if I have three vertices and three edges connected triangle-style, then after I 'collapse' one of the edges I would want the new graph (or multigraph I guess) to consist of two vertices which are connected to each other by two edges.

Comment: If you contract a loop, you lose one edge and no vertices.  

Comment: The transformation does not contract loops; by 'two vertices connected by an edge' I meant two distinct vertices.

Comment: Damiano, it's minus the Euler characteristic.

Comment: Ohai, the Euler characteristic is a homotopy invariant of topological spaces, and edge contraction is a homotopy equivalence.  (OK, you can get what you want without getting into these technicalities, but this is the topological point of view.)

Comment: One more thing: the non-simplicial case is fine.  In this case, the graph is a CW-complex, and eveything still works.  (Though, as observed, you're not allowed to contract a loop to a point - that's not a homotopy equivalence.)

Comment: OK, this really is my last comment.  The quantity $1-\chi(G)$ also has a natural algebraic interpretation: it's the rank of the fundamental group (or of the first homology group---take your pick).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whether you're considering a multigraph (which may have multiple edges and/or loops) or a  simple graph, both are CW complexes.  For any finite CW complex $G$, the *Euler characteristic* $\chi(G)$ is defined as the alternating sum (#0-cells)-(#1-cells)+(#2-cells)-...  (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic)). Thus for a finite graph, the Euler characteristic is $|V|-|E|$.  It's a homotopy invariant, and the operation of collapsing one edge and its vertices to a single vertex is a homotopy equivalence, so any function of $|V|-|E|$ is invariant under this operation.

When the graph is connected, the quantity $|E|-|V|+1$ ($=1-\chi(G)$) is the smallest number of edges that must be removed to yield a graph with no cycles, called the *cyclomatic number* or the *circuit rank* (see [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircuitRank.html)).  But if the graph is not connected, then "$+1$" must be replaced by "$+k$," where $k$ is the number of components.

Comment: The cyclomatic number is also called the first Betti number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity  
(This is an edit answering my own question that I asked about 10 minutes ago)

Answer (score 5):

*Cyclomatic number* or *excess* are indeed common names for the quantity $|E|-|V|+1$ (as other answers mention).
Let me add that the correct quantity to consider when you have $k$ components in your graph $G$ is $c(G):=|E|-|V|+k$. Then $c(G)=0$ means exactly that $G$ is a forest.
Also, the number $c(G)$ occurs in algebraic graph theory as the dimension of the [cycle space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space) of the graph $G$.

Answer (score 1):

As Jack Lee mentions, the related quantity $|V|-|E|$ is often called the *Euler characteristic* of the graph.  I have also heard $|E|-|V|+1$ called the *cyclomatic number*.

Comment: @Tony: Actually, the Euler characteristic is $|V|-|E|$.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My answer comes from the random graphs community. In the book [Random Graphs](https://www.amazon.ca/Random-Graphs-Svante-Janson/dp/0471175412), the quantity "edges minus vertices" is called the *excess*, which is quite standard terminology at least in random graphs.

In [these](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4730) [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3629) we call the quantity "edges minus vertices plus one" the *surplus*. In an important paper in the area, [Aldous](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-25/issue-2/Brownian-excursions-critical-random-graphs-and-the-multiplicative-coalescent/10.1214/aop/1024404421.full) calls edges beyond those in a spanning tree both surplus edges and excess edges.